# Discord.py - Load guild prefixes when the bot starts (MySQL)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot using **discord.py** and **mysql**, and I am currently loading the guild prefix every time that a message is sent:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM servers WHERE guild = {message.guild.id}")
    prefix = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

The problem is that the bot is getting bigger, and laggy too. So I want to load all the prefixes when the bot starts, on the `on_ready()` event. Using **discord.js**, it would be something like that:

```
const guildPrefixes = new Map();

client.on('ready', () => {

    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        connection.query(
            `SELECT prefix FROM servers WHERE guild = '${guild.id}'`
        ).then(result => {
            guildPrefixes.set(guild.id, result[0][0].prefix);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

});

client.on('message', async (message) => {

    const prefix = guildPrefixes.get(message.guild.id);
    // code here...

});
```

How could I do this using **discord.py**?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have guild specific prefixes? `on_ready()` won't have a guild.

Comment: I think that I will have to use something like ```for guild in client.guilds``` and then save the prefix for each guild. I just don't know how to do that in python. In js I could use Map()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through `client.guilds`

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.prefixes = {}
    for i in client.guilds:
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM servers WHERE guild = {i.id}")
        prefix = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        client.prefixes[i.id] = prefix

@client.event
async def on_message(m):
    prefix = client.prefixes.get(m.guild.id)
    # code
```